# FileMaker :- Compare textbox values with OBBC SQL DB

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to implement an Login module where,I need to Compare the list of values in  SQL DB. Here i want to compare text  box entered values with SQL DB.
Please share any views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your SQL DB. You can add your SQL DB as ESS or you can use "Execute SQL" and run a SQL query on ODBC DNS to your database.

If you are in 16 and your SQL has any API, you can call them through CURL. You can do the same with previous versions of FileMaker using plugins.